# Vector of named vectors results in compiler errors

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a vector of vectors each with predefined size.  My instinctive first try was to do (in C++ Builder XE2 a UnicodeString is a string class used in its components, etc.  Assume that Expression is a UnicodeString and Length() returns the number of characters it contains):

```
        vector <UnicodeString> StringVector ('\0',2);     
        vector <StringVector> ExpressionArray(Expression.Length());
```

But my compiler hates this.  What's wrong with it?

Another option is this:

```
  vector <vector <UnicodeString> > ExpressionArray(Expression.Length());
```

But instead of a Expression.Length()-element vector of 2-element empty-string vectors I get a Expression.Length()-element vector of empty vectors.

I suppose I could use a resize statement, but I am unsure how to do this with 2-dimensional vectors.

How do I write to something like this anyhow?

The following code throws an exception on the first line after the opening brace:

```
for (int i=0;i<Expression.Length();i++)
    {
        ExpressionArray[0][i]=Expression.SubString(i+1,1); //i+1 because UnicodeStrings are 1-based
        ExpressionArray[1][i]="B";
        OnClickStatusInfo->Lines->Add(ExpressionArray[0][i])+"\t"+ExpressionArray[1][i];
    }
```

What's wrong?  It strikes me that I may have misused the subscript operators.

Thanks a lot,

sbarringtonleigh

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> vector <UnicodeString> StringVector ('\0',2);     
> vector <StringVector> ExpressionArray(Expression.Length());
> ```
>
> But my compiler hates this. What's wrong with it?

`StringVector` is variable, when `vector` expects to have type in `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 forms of vector ctor (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Judging by the number of arguments, you meant the second, "fill" consructor.

`vector <UnicodeString> StringVector ('\0',2)`;

Your first attempt looks as if you have swapped the size and the value arguments. Even if you swap the arguments, your `UnicodeString` is supposed to have a constructor which takes a single `char` - which looks odd, and it probably can't.

`vector <StringVector> ExpressionArray(Expression.Length());`

Your second attempt should work, provided the return type of `Expression.Length()` is compatible with `vector::size_type`, `StringVector` has the default constructor and the copy constructor. Perhaps one of these conditions does not hold.